# Is there a way to use Rust's serde / serde_json to "patch" a structure?

Tags: rust, serde

Is there a reasonably simple way to use serde/serde_json to take an existing struct and update only those fields that are present in the JSON? This basically amounts to setting a default value at runtime rather than at compile time by implementing the Default trait or a default value generator function.

This seems like a really common use case when you have a RESTful API where you want to submit updates to state, modifying only specified fields and leaving unspecified fields unchanged.

I could do it by deserializing to the dynamic Value type and then doing a big match or if/else block to update fields, but that's verbose and ugly. I'm wondering if serde has anything to handle this.

Comment: Pretty sure *serde* is only concerned with *ser*ialization and *de*serialization; patching/merging/diffing isn't really part of its feature set. A crate like [json_patch](https://crates.io/crates/json-patch) may help you, but I'm not so sure. A more robust strategy is to define an `*Update` struct with `Option`-al fields and deserialize it that way. It may be more work, but I've found it more flexible in the long run.

Comment: I think json_patch might do basically what I want, though it's not as straightforward as having serde do it.

Comment: I agree that it would make sense for serde to incorporate this directly.  Serde has a method for deserializing into an existing struct, so it already has the ability to update.  It just needs to not panic if there are missing fields.  Here is a  playground to illustrate:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bccf10311e413af139f3fee957a1e747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serde doesn't support anything like this. If I needed to do it, I would maybe create a parallel structure where all of the fields are optional:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct MyData {
    foo: String,
    bar: u64,
    wibble: bool,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct MyDataPatch {
    foo: Option<String>,
    bar: Option<u64>,
    wibble: Option<bool>,
}

impl MyData {
    pub fn patch(&mut self, update: MyDataPatch) {
        if let Some(foo) = update.foo {
            self.foo = foo;
        }
        if let Some(bar) = update.bar {
            self.bar = bar;
        }
        if let Some(wibble) = update.wibble {
            self.wibble = wibble;
        }
    }
}
```

This is more code duplication, but less runtime overhead.

If I had a lot of these, then I'd generate all of that with a macro, rather than write it by hand. You could do that with a derivable trait, something like:

```
trait Patch {
    type Patch; // Self with all optional fields
    fn patch(&mut self, patch: &Self::Patch);
}
```

Comment: Not sure a trait help

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if I could write a macro to derive that. Dunno. But that would work. I also think I will suggest something like this to serde if nobody has suggested it yet, since it seems like a no brainer feature for anyone implementing an idempotent REST-ful style interface.

Comment: @Stargateur The trait would help if you wanted to implement it as a derive macro :)

Comment: @Stargateur It also creates a 1-1 mapping between types. `<T as Patch>::Patch` is a type level function with argument `T`, that returns the "patched" type for T.